# Replace multiple values with jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a variable in jinja2: test1 = "this is value1 and this is value2"

with:

```
{{ test1 | replace("value1","my_value1")  }}
```

I can replace value1 but I also need to replace value2 how can I do this?

I tried:

```
{{ test1 | replace("value1","my_value1") | replace("value2","my_value2") }}
```

But this then only replaces value2.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your expression seems to work just fine.  If I create a template with
the jinja2 expression from your question:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template('{{ test1 | replace("value1","my_value1") | replace("value2","my_value2") }}')
```

And then render it, passing in a value for `test1` that contains both
of the target replacement strings:

```
>>> output = t.render(test1="this has both value1 and value2")
```

I get a string that has both values replaced:

```
>>> print (output)
this has both my_value1 and my_value2
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

currently you can replace variable by jinja

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#replace

```
{{ "Hello World"|replace("Hello", "Goodbye") }}
    -> Goodbye World

{{ "aaaaargh"|replace("a", "d'oh, ", 2) }}
    -> d'oh, d'oh, aaargh
```